# why are my rows looping 12000 times when they should be looping 170 times?

Tags: php, mysql

I am running a while/foreach on a mySQL database and an array to check if it exists or not. It's supposed to loop 170 times but it loops over 12000 times. Why is that?

```
$my_rows = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($run_query)){

    $my_rows[] = $row;
    foreach($my_rows as $row){
        if(in_array_r($row['name'], $products)){
            echo "Exists";
        } else {
            echo "Does not exist";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: remove the hole foreach, each `while` $my_rows grows and each time the `foreach` is running

Comment: Hah! Thanks :) If you add an answer I'll gladly accept it!

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$my_rows = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($run_query)){

    $my_rows[] = $row;

    if(in_array_r($row['name'], $products)){

        echo "Exists";

    } else {

        echo "Does not exist";

    }

}
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 3):

What should be happening here is that you assign the result of `mysql_fetch_assoc` to `$my_rows` and then loop over the contents of `$my_rows`. One loop. One of those loops doesn't need to exist.

```
$my_rows = mysql_fetch_assoc(...);
foreach($my_rows as $row){ ...do stuff here... }
```